# unable to fetch the id of dynamically generated button in jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery click not working for dynamically created items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484295/jquery-click-not-working-for-dynamically-created-items)

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn').click(function(){

                var createInput=$("<input type='button'>");
                createInput.attr("id","close1");
                createInput.attr("value","close");
                $('#outer-div').append(createInput);
            });

            $("#close1").click(function(){
                alert('hi');
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='outer-div'>
        <input id='btn' type='button' value='click here'/>
    </div>
```

**What's wrong with the code. I am not getting the alert when i click the dynamically generated button named as close. Please help it out**

Comment: One of n number of questions that are related to this issue stackoverflow.com/questions/9484295/… – undefined 30 mins ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){

            var createInput=$("<input type='button'>");
            createInput.attr("id","close1");
            createInput.attr("value","close");
            $('#outer-div').append(createInput);
        });

        $(document).on('click', "#close1", function(){
            alert('hi');
        });
    });
```

The problem with

```
$("#close1").click...
```

is that it adds an event handler to nothing, as the collection is empty when you execute this line. The [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function fixes that.

BTW, it's recommended to put your script at the end of the body instead of in the head.