# jQuery dynamically generated content - clicks not working

Tags: dynamic, jquery

I have a page where I dynamically add in divs, as such:

```
$(divCol).insertAfter(parentNewRow.children('.edCol:last'));
```

This inserts another duplicate div after the last `.edCol` div. Everything works well, except for the fact that with the new `.edCol` div, none of the buttons work anymore. All the jQuery functions that work perfectly on the original div now do nothing. The code is identical in the new div, all the classes are the same etc, yet nothing works.

Clearly I am missing something. Can anyone shed any light on this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you binding the click event to the divs?

Comment: show your html and more code,also check on functionality of jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery click not working for dynamically created items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484295/jquery-click-not-working-for-dynamically-created-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery documentation indicates `live()` is deprecated you should use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Here's an example that you can see working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzYXs/2/).

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').on('click', 'div', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
    });

    $('#container').append($('<div>BLE</div>'));
});​
```

And the HTML that goes with it:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>BLA</div>
</div>​
```

---

**EDIT**

Please check out the following fiddle that's a more complete example and will probably clarify your doubts about how the `on()` method is used: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NzYXs/8/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        First you have these buttons with the bound click handler<br/>
        <button>One</button><br/>
        <button>Two</button><br/>
        <button>Three</button><br/>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<button id="load-btn">Click this button to load the buttons below in the &lt;div&gt; above</button>
<hr/>
<div id="content">
    <div>
        These buttons are going to be loaded above.<br/>
        <button>Four</button><br/>
        <button>Five</button><br/>
        <button>Six</button><br/>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**​JS**

```
$(function() {
    // Bind click handler to the #load-btn which will
    // dynamically load the lower div content inside the upper div.
    $('#load-btn').on('click', function() {
        $('#container').append($('#content').html());
    });

    // Bind another click handler to all <button>s that exist at the moment
    // and that could be added dynamically inside the #container element.
    $('#container').on('click', 'button', function() {
        console.log('button ' + $(this).html() + ' clicked.');
    });
});​
```

Comment: Your current method of using `.on()` won't work for dynamically added elements.

Comment: It is suggested to not bind events to document, either, but a container element.

Comment: @Daedalus Right again, thanks for the observations. Just improved the example.

Comment: Hello Juan - thanks for this info, but I can't seem to make this work. I am not sure how to implement this. I have tried every combination without any luck. I can't really post the code, as there is so much code attached to this dynamic div. Basically, the new div that gets generated has 7 buttons within it that are attached to other jQuery controls. The div gets inserted perfectly, but none of the internal 7 buttons work at all. Do I implement the `.on` on the click that generates the new div, or on the internal button controls for the new div?

Comment: @xtiaan I just added a more detailed example.

Comment: Juan - thank you, that worked. But wow, very complicated. If you have a moment, can you explain the principles of why this works? I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's live() method. 
Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

REF: http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$("p").live("click", function(){
$(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

using ['live' binding](http://api.jquery.com/live/) you can attach an event to elements in the future as well.

```
$('a').live('click' , function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".my_Class", function (e) {
        alert("Works Fine");
    });
```

Comment: This works fine with every element Static or Dynamic and less browser dependency.