# li.click does not work on dynamic created element

Tags: jquery

i am creating new list elements dynamically. When clicking these elements I want execute code. 
The event `$("li").click()` only fires for my default list item `<li>I am a default list element</li>` but not for any newly created ones. Please see my code below:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document.ready callback');

    $("input#input2").click( function() {
        console.log('input#input2.click: ' + $("input#input1").val() + ' added to list');
        $("ul").append('<li>'+$("input#input1").val()+'</li>');
    });

    $("li").click( function() {
        console.log('li.click: ' +$(this).text());
    });

    // Info
    // .on('click', function()
    // .live('click', function()
    // did not solve this problem
});<script><html>
<body>
    Enter some stuff: <input type="text" id="input1" value="stuff">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="input2" value="Submit stuff to List">
    <p>stuff list!</p>
    <ul>
        <li>I am a default list element</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements#_=_) but unfortunately that did not solve my current case.

thx y'all!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery click not working for dynamically created items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484295/jquery-click-not-working-for-dynamically-created-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delegating it to the closest static parent(which is present in the document) is better than using `document` (performance wise)

try this

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  console.log('li.click: ' +$(this).text());
});
```

you can read more about `on()` events [here](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html)

Comment: awesome! that answers my additional question :) would it be better to always use "$(document).on()" instead of "$(some Element)".click() ?? (argh..sorry not used to the comment function ..yet

Comment: would it be better to always use "$(document).on()" instead of "$(some Element)".click() ??  (argh..sorry not used to the comment function ..yet)

Comment: `$(some Element)".click() `  is better if your someElement is not added dynamically... if added dynamically.. `on` is preffered as `live` use to do this before .. but is depricated and removed in jquery 1.9 version

Comment: @Kim: You should use delegates for dynamically added elements, or when you want to catch the same event on a whole lot of elements, otherwise just catch the event on each element.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for bind event on dynamically create elements instead of click and delegate the event to parent element or document. You can read more about on [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    console.log('li.click: ' +$(this).text());
});
```

Comment: would it be better to always use "$(document).on()" instead of "$(some
Element)".click() ??

Answer (score 0):

The click event is only being bound to the elements that are selected in `$("li")` when it is called. Try adding a click event binder to the script you're using to add elements to bind a new click behavior each time you add an element.

Answer (score 0):

The `live` method would work, but it's replaced by the use of the `on` method to create a delegate. You need to supply a parent element to apply the delegate to, and a selector to filter out the elements that event should be triggered on:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
```

Comment: Why are you mentioning `live`?

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice that line