# Dynamicaly created input element with jquery

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I added dynamicaly input field with jquery. And now I want to make event with jquery "focusout" but its not triggering... any ideas ?

This input is created dynamicaly with jQuery.

```
<input type="text" id="input_id" name="input_name" value="" />

$("#input_id").focusout(function(){
     alert("test");
});
```

SOLVED UPDATE:

```
$("#input_id").live('focusout', function() {
```

Comment: Yes, read the documentation on `on`.

Comment: SO needs to move the favorite button further away from the down-vote button.

Comment: I tried this: $("#input_id").on('focusout', 'input', function()  but not working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery click not working for dynamically created items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484295/jquery-click-not-working-for-dynamically-created-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
$("#input_id").live('focusout', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

While you creating input field give an id for the input element. `<input type='text' id='myfield' />` Now you can write code for focus out / blur like below

```
$("#myfield").blur(function(){
    // Your code here
   // If you want to Get the value from that field ?
   var val1 = $("#myfield").val();
});
```

Comment: as you can see the ID is already created ...

Comment: Put your jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function(){ // your jquery code goes here });` some times this will be needed. Or you can try .hover instead that contains two function on mouseover and mouseout