# Preserving event handlers when replacing html in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a jQuery function as:

```
function linkify(parent, regex, url) {
  var children = parent.children('main,article,div,p,li,ul,ol,span');
  const re = RegExp(`(${regex})(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)`, 'ig');
  children.each(function() {
    linkify($(this), regex, url);
    $(this).html(
      $(this)
        .html()
        .replace(re, `<a rel="nofollow" href="${url}">$1</a>`)
    );
  });
}
```

It's a recursive function that goes down the DOM tree, and finds occurrences of words in the body text, and converts them into a link if found.

It works great. The problem I have is that when I do:

```
$(this).html(
  $(this).html()
)
```

(i.e. copying the HTML), it discards all bound event handlers. This means in a real page, it can break things like JS menus.

**How can I copy the HTML code, while preserving anything bound to it?**

PS I have checked other similar posts, however this is different, in that this code will be included in an arbitrary page- I need to develop a general solution, not one specific to particular page.

Comment: you could only replace `text nodes` with `<a>${text node}</a>`, so, without replacing the whole `innerHTML` you would preserve its behaviour....

Comment: I can experiment with that. Going the other way, is it possible to copy over the bindings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click not working after clearing and appending the html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866142/click-not-working-after-clearing-and-appending-the-html)

Comment: use `clone` of `this` with `true` so that binds not removed, then add `this` `clone` to `html`

Comment: @DupinderSingh how do I assign the binds in this case? Can you give a short example?

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript to copy the HTML and not jQuery for this specific action

Comment: How does this preserve the bindings?

Comment: just do var old = el.innerHTML; el.outerHTML = `<a href="old">old</a>`

Comment: I need to replace text using regex, not just wrap other elements. I might be able to make a version of this work though, I will experiment.

Comment: @cjm2671 I mean just use that in your regex function, I think the "this" variable is a real HTML node, if so just use that in place of "el"