# .remove() doesn't achieve desired effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/L11h2b50/3/

I'm trying to write a lightbox script, which can open images when clicked. As you can see in the fiddle, that part works. But closing the image by clicking the lightbox in order to execute the function .remove() doesn't quite work out. Why is that?

```
$(".discuss-entry img").each(function() {
    var image = $(this);
    var src = image.attr("src");
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var imageWidth = image.outerWidth();
    var imageHeight = image.outerHeight();

    var left = ((windowWidth-imageWidth)/2)
    var top = ((windowHeight-imageHeight)/2)

    if(image.closest("a")[0]===undefined) {
        image.on("click",function(){
            $("<div class='lightbox'><img src='"+src+"' style='top: "+top+"px; left: "+left+"px' /></div>").appendTo("body");
        });
        $(".lightbox").on("click", "img", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery click not working for dynamically created items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484295/jquery-click-not-working-for-dynamically-created-items)

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to call `$(".lightbox").remove();` instead of `this` which refers to the image only.

Comment: Try attaching youre click handler to the element that you're appending to(body) rather than attaching to .light box:   $("div.lightbox img").click(REMOVE).append to(body)

Comment: http://mycodefixes.blogspot.hu/2011/01/jquery-binding-events-to-dynamic-dom.html here is the reason

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/L11h2b50/9/**

Comment: @Juhana it's not a duplicate, since i've already use the solution of that question

Comment: No you haven't. You're still binding the event to the dynamically created element, not its static parent.

Comment: mentally walk through when element gets added and when you bind the event handler. Since `lightbox` doesn't get added until ***after*** user triggered event and you add event handler before the user triggered event, element doesn't exist when you are binding the new click handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting `.lightbox` before it's created, you should select and add the event once it's created, like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/L11h2b50/6/)

### JavaScript

```
$(".discuss-entry img").each(function() {
    var image = $(this);
    var src = image.attr("src");
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var imageWidth = image.outerWidth();
    var imageHeight = image.outerHeight();
    
    var left = ((windowWidth-imageWidth)/2)
    var top = ((windowHeight-imageHeight)/2)
    
    if(image.closest("a")[0]===undefined) {
        image.on("click",function(){
            $("<div class='lightbox'><img src='"+src+"' style='top: "+top+"px; left: "+left+"px' /></div>").appendTo("body");
            $(".lightbox").on("click", function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
        
    }
});
```

Also I changed `.on("click","img"..)` for `.on("click"..)` so that it removes the complete lightbox and not just the image, but feel free to change that back.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Try putting that event into an onclick on your lightbox div:

```
if(image.closest("a")[0]===undefined) {
    image.on("click",function(){
        $("<div class='lightbox' onclick='$(this).remove()' ><img src='"+src+"' style='top: "+top+"px; left: "+left+"px' /></div>").appendTo("body");
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L11h2b50/10/

Comment: why mix unobtrusive and inline script? Defeats the purpose of using unobtrusive script in the first place. Event delegation is a better solution