# Javascript. function is not working in .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, append

HTML.

```
<div id="listsalon">
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" >

   </ul>
</div>
```

JS.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

   companyname = arr[i].CompanyName;

   picture = arr[i].Picture;

   address = arr[i].Address;

   $("#listsalon ul").append("<li class='ui-corner-all'>" + 
                        "<a id=" + '"' + "salon" + (i + 1) + '"' + "><img src='" + picture +           
                        "'style='height:160px; width:200px;' class='ui-corner-all'>" +
                        "<h2 style='font-size:13px'>" + companyname + "</h2>" +
                        "<p style='font-size:10px'>" + address + "</p>" +
                       "</a></li>");
                }

    $("#salon1").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "salon.html"
    });
```

Problem:
So first I pull data and put in 3 variables, companyname, picture and address. i have x sets of these data. i want to put in a list form. i am able to list out, but the function doesn't recognise the id and it does not work. please help. ty

Comment: replace `$("#salon1")` with `$("#salon"+(i + 1))` cause your `id` should be unique on single page

Comment: the binding of the button is outside the loop. it doesnt work this way. i feel the problem is in the append. when i created this id, DOM tree does not recognize it

Comment: cross-check your `a` tag. Is your id generating correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `#salon1` element is being created dynamically. Moreover, [`.bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) in JQuery is deprecated. For such cases you should use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#listsalon").on("click", "a#salon1", function () {
    window.location = "salon.html"
});
```

More at [jQuery click not working for dynamically created items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9484295)

Proof of work

```js
var arr = [{"CompanyName": "A", "Picture": "https://via.placeholder.com/140x100", "Address": 1}, {"CompanyName": "B", "Picture": "https://via.placeholder.com/140x100", "Address": 2}];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var companyname = arr[i].CompanyName;
  var picture = arr[i].Picture;
  var address = arr[i].Address;
  $("#listsalon ul").append("<li class='ui-corner-all'>" + 
                            "<a href='#' id=" + '"' + "salon" + (i + 1) + '"' + "><img src='" + picture +           
                            "'style='height:160px; width:200px;' class='ui-corner-all'>" +
                            "<h2 style='font-size:13px'>" + companyname + "</h2>" +
                            "<p style='font-size:10px'>" + address + "</p>" +
                            "</a></li>");
   $("#listsalon").on("click", "a#salon"+(i+1), function () {
      alert("Redirecting...");
      window.location = "salon.html"
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listsalon">
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" ></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: nope it does not work. i personally feel the problem is coming from the append. something to do with the id not being recognised.

Comment: @Jason seems to be working fine for me. I have updated answer with a proof of work.

Comment: Tyvm. it works better when i use Sergio answer(the comment above urs). He/She uses document.createElement which i think is a better solution. I used ur code for the buttons, it helps to differentiate which buttons is which. Ur time spent here is appreciated. Once again ty :)

Answer (score 1):

To add event listeners to dynamically created objects, you need to create DOM objects using `document.createElement`. This lets you hold to the actual element even before appending it.

Then, you can use it like you would use any other object retrieved using a query string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let array = ["a", "b", "c"];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let el = document.createElement('li');
    $(el).html(array[i]);
    
    $(el).on('click', function() {
      alert('Click!');
    });
    
    $("#listsalon ul").append(el);
  }
});
```

```css
#listsalon ul li {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listsalon">
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" >
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS styles are just for clarity.

Comment: Yea this works. Tyvm. and to differentiate the button i clicked i used the code provided by Saharsh(the comment below urs). Rly appreciate ur time to help me!

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful when adding event listeners inside of loops, because they are cumulative and you could end up running the same function hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample. `.bind()` in `JQuery` is `deprecated`. For such cases, you should use `.on()`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $("#listsalon ul").append("<li class='ui-corner-all'>" + 
      "<a id=" + '"' + "salon" + (i + 1) + '"' + ">"+(i + 1)+"</a></li>");
    $("#salon"+(i + 1)).on("click", function () {
        alert('clicked')
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listsalon">
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
```

You were defining your `click` function outside `for loop`. That's why `DOM` didn't recognize your `id`

Comment: I would not advise that you use `.bind` since that has been removed from jquery since v 3., Use `.on()`

Comment: I missed this inflow to solve the issue. let me add it